# Geo intent extension to provide routing

Tags: android, geo

The [Geo Intent scheme](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common.html#Maps) in Android

```
geo:latitude,longitude?z=zoom
```

Describes a generic way how to show a place on a map. But how to do that for **routing** to a place?

There are tons of Apps just implementing the maps.google.com url
schema as the de-facto standard *Intent* handler (MapBox, Here Maps, OSM)  for anything beyond showing a place (which is covered by the geo scheme).

So as an App developer I might have to think, which url should I support 
routing (navigating) to a place:

- maps.google.com/maps?saddr=...&daddr=...
- www.openstreetmap.org/directions?engine=osrm_car&route=...
- here.com/directions/A/B
  ...

So as a developer I need to specify which scheme I need to use in order to
open a nnavigation experience. Which would you choose? In 99% of the cases google maps, because other apps also implement its scheme, and by that I am enabling my user to choose which experience he likes to open ans his preferred app.

Now with [Android M](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/index.html) this will have an end because users will be always taken to google maps app, instead of choosing between other apps, which may handle this url scheme as well.

So my question is, is there an alternative standard for navigation or routing?

If no maybe it would be possible to extending the geo scheme to include routing options, and publicly document that.

Answer (score 0):

The [Android M article you refer to is about **App Links**](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/index.html) which defines mappings from http(s) urls to android apps.

Example:

- a link to `http://maps.google.com` will open google maps in android-6 because  google maps has registered an App Link for urls starting with `http://maps.google.com`.
- a link to `http://www.openstreetmap.org` will open a web-browser (if there is no android app link registered for "www.openstreetmap.org"

App-Links have nothing to do with the [geo-uri standard](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-mayrhofer-geo-uri-00) .

An android app with an [intent-filter for "geo:" uri-s](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common.html#Maps) will be presented by the chooser if you request a geo-uri

Comment: Hey thanks for the nice answer. I am well aware how App Links work, and this is the problem. If I implement an App where I like to route from A to B I might think of using an intent with maps.google.com/saddr=...daddr-... So a lot of apps will be able to open that scheme because it is a public API. In pre M devices you would see an App Chooser, if you have multipe maps Apps installed. Now this will go directly to Google Maps. And all other apps implementing those scheme will be cut out.

Comment: Did you mean that an app that wants to parse the html-result or webservice-call to `http://maps.google.com/...` might fail in android-m because this http(s)-request is redirected to the google-maps app? I still donot see what the "geo:" uri has to do with this.

Comment: Maybe the question about the geo intent is pointing in the wrong direction. I am concerned about the fact that starting a navigation is done mainly with `maps.google.com` and not with a generic intent like i.e. `navigate:FROM:TO` and now that Android M starts to bind those intents with App Links, all the intent traffic is going to Google Maps. Thats why I would love to have a generic intent which is not bound to google and can be implemented by various platforms.